# How to calculate the shear force, and the bending and torsion moments on a wing?

Tags: wing, aircraft-physics

I want to calculate the loads (shear force, bending and torsion moments). Assuming I have the force distribution along all the surfaces of the aircraft, my starting point is to consider the wing (and other surfaces whose loads I want to calculate) to behave like a cantilever. So, I've got these formulas:

$$
S_z =
\int_z^{b/2}
F
\;dy
$$

$$
M =
\int_z^{b/2}
S_z
\;dy
$$

Where

Sz = shear force in point z;
Mz = Bending Moment in point z;
F = Lift Distribution;
b = Wingspan;

and the coordinate system is as follows:

[image]

Are these formulas correct, and how can I calculate the torsion moment?

Comment: Your wingspan coordinate is y, therefore the integration should run from 0 to b/2. The z coordinate in your sketch is confusing - should that not be the force direction? Shear is in z and bending around x, so it should be $S_z$ and $M_x$. If you add $M_y$ you will also have a term for torsion. And there is no point z, only one like (x=0; y=0; z=0) or so.

Comment: @PeterKämpf if you look z in this case is not an axis, but a generic value along y. the formulas are to compute S and M at z.

Comment: @Federico: In the sketch, z looks like a length along y. Then it is a point. Normally, it should be the third coordinate, which is missing. A point along y should be y=something, not z. Clarity in asking often gives you the answer already.

Comment: @PeterKämpf "In the sketch, z looks like a length along y." exactly my point. Also, in the question "Sz = shear force in point z". So yes, it is a point, not a coordinate as you first said. Sure, usually it would be, but not here and is quite clear.

Comment: "z" is a point along the y-axis. Sz, for example, means the shear force applied to point z of the 'beam' that supports the structure of the wing